# STTwitter CFNetwork internal error NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth, cfnetwork, sttwitter

After looking at this link [API mode error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054795/twitter-api-application-only-mode-authentication) I corrected some code using STTwitter.  This eradicated one error but made me notice a new CFNetwork error.  Whenever I try to fetch statuses using either getHomeTimelineSinceID or getUserTimelinewithScreenName, the error "CFNetwork internal error (0xc01a:/SourceCache/CFNetwork/CFNetwork-695.1.5/Foundation/NSURLRequest.mm:798)" pops up in the debugger.  After debugging I found the error pops right after [r Asynchronous] (line 272 of STTwitterAppOnly.m).  I got to this spot by stepping into verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock.

The code I am currently using:

```
   [twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *bearerToken) {

    [twitter getHomeTimelineSinceID:nil
                               count:20
                        successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses) {

                            NSLog(@"-- statuses: %@", statuses);


                            self.twitterFeed = statuses;

                            [self.tableView reloadData];

                        } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                        }];
```

And I have also tried:

```
        [twitter getUserTimelineWithScreenName:@"Dandelion_2014"
                              successBlock:^(NSArray *statuses) {

                                  self.twitterFeed = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:statuses];

                                  [self.tableView reloadData];

                              } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

                                  NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);

                              }];
```

I'm not sure what is causing this error, does anybody have insight?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but there may be something wrong in [STHTTPRequest](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter/blob/master/STTwitter/Vendor/STHTTPRequest.m).

Comment: Your exactly right, the exception is being thrown by [request setHTTPMethod:_HTTPMethod] (line 357, requestByAddingCredentialsToURL:)

Going to do some more digging to see if I can find the issue.

Comment: After some more investigation and a bit of looking into the Apple documentation, it looks like `[setHTTPMethod]` is obsolete in iOS 8 (I am using the beta).  I ran the same code on an older device using iOS 7.1 and the error did not come up.  However, neither did a tableview of twitter feed entries.  Going to keep looking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I found the issue.

iOS 8 raises a runtime warning when setting `-[NSURLRequest HTTPMethod]` to `nil`.

I updated [STHTTPRequest](https://github.com/nst/STHTTPRequest) and [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter).

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Quick link to the commit in question (for STHTTPRequest, which worked well for me): https://github.com/nst/STHTTPRequest/commit/2b7ef629475e0c8a73a6314f5ac1f4a4c79ba083

Comment: sorry took me awhile to get back to this, work caught up to me and my side projects got put on hold.  Thanks so much for the update!