# Xcode 6 giving the CFNetwork Internal error

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6

I recently installed Xcode 6 and when I tried to run the app in simulator it runs fine ,but it logs the following error. I have no idea what this error is about. Can anyone say how to fix

```
CFNetwork internal error (0xc01a:/SourceCache/CFNetwork_Sim/CFNetwork-711.0.6/Foundation/NSURLRequest.mm:798)
```

Comment: Does this error cause a crash or does it just log a message?  What kind of networking do you do in your app?

Comment: It doesn't cause crash. It's just the message. I use twitter feed and UIDocumentInteractionController in my app . Is this error has anything to do with NSURLRequest?

Comment: Hmm I am not sure.  Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223542/sttwitter-cfnetwork-internal-error-nsurlrequest

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will be the solution for everyone, but it fixed my App.

I was sending a Multipart form-data POST request with:

```
conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] init...]
[conn setDelegate:myDelegate];
[conn start];
```

And this was causing the CFNetwork internal error, so annoying.

I changed it with:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsync...]
```

and it now works like a charm.