# How To post Tweets using STTwitter in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, twitter-oauth, sttwitter

i am used STTweeter for posting Tweets but it showing EXC_BAD_ACESS Error
and showing error STTwitterTwitter ErrorDomain code 220

[image]
My code

```
    - (void)setOAuthToken:(NSString *)token oauthVerifier:(NSString *)verifier {

  // in case the user has just authenticated through WebViewVC
  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES
                           completion:^{//
                           }];

  [_twitter postAccessTokenRequestWithPIN:verifier
      successBlock:^(NSString *oauthToken, NSString *oauthTokenSecret,
                     NSString *userID, NSString *screenName) {
          NSLog(@"-- screenName: %@", screenName);

          self.twitter = [STTwitterAPI
              twitterAPIAppOnlyWithConsumerKey:_consumerKeyTextField.text
                                consumerSecret:_consumerSecretTextField.text];

          [_twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *username) {

              [_twitter postStatusUpdate:@"tweet text"
                       inReplyToStatusID:nil
                                latitude:nil
                               longitude:nil
                                 placeID:nil
                      displayCoordinates:nil
                                trimUser:nil
                            successBlock:nil
                              errorBlock:nil];
              NSLog(@"Sucess");

          } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"_____ERROR____%@", error);
          }];

          _loginStatusLabel.text = screenName;

      }
      errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {

          _loginStatusLabel.text = [error localizedDescription];
          NSLog(@"-- %@", [error localizedDescription]);
      }];
}
```

Comment: At which point does the code behaving as you expect? Can you post the logs?

Comment: I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error....and error showing STTwitterErrorDomain code:220 Your Credentials do not allow to this resource.STHTTPRequest-code:403

Comment: You cannot post if you haven't authenticated a user. Also, you shouldn't re-instantiate STTwitterAPI in the successBlock. See the STTwitterDemoiOS and STTwitterDemoOSX for working examples.

Comment: you haven't authenticated a user. means how to get authenticate my user ?and in successBlock i put like this successBlock:^(NSDictionary *status)
             {
       NSLog(@"===1===Sucess");

             }errorBlock:^(NSError *error)
             {
                 NSLog(@"_____ERROR ===1==%@",error);}];
even  though getting  STTwitterErrorDomain code:220